# Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I was using `SimpleExoPlayerView` till now and now updated my Exoplayer library to latest and it is removed and has been asked to replace with `PlayerView` But it is also deprecated and has been asked to implement `StyledPlayerView` But after implementing the `StyledPlayerView` I am getting a crash `Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView`

**app level build.gradle:**

```
android {
...
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
...
}

dependencies {
...
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.1'
...
}
```

**xml File:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_exoplayer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/done_tv"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="9:16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2">

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/exoplayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Crash Log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.package/com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #113 in com.app.package:layout/activity_app_tutorial: Binary XML file line #113 in com.app.package:layout/activity_app_tutorial: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3611)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #113 in com.app.package:layout/activity_app_tutorial: Binary XML file line #113 in com.app.package:layout/activity_app_tutorial: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #113 in com.app.package:layout/activity_app_tutorial: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.inflateInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:1409)
        at com.app.package.databinding.ActivityAppTutorialBinding.inflate(ActivityAppTutorialBinding.java:99)
        at com.app.package.databinding.ActivityAppTutorialBinding.inflate(ActivityAppTutorialBinding.java:85)
        at com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity$mAppTutorialBinding$2.invoke(AppTutorialActivity.kt:59)
        at com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity$mAppTutorialBinding$2.invoke(AppTutorialActivity.kt:59)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity.getMAppTutorialBinding(AppTutorialActivity.kt:59)
        at com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity.onCreate(AppTutorialActivity.kt:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8006)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3584)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
2022-04-08 10:59:06.604 32468-32468/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in com.app.package:layout/exo_styled_settings_list: Binary XML file line #16 in com.app.package:layout/exo_styled_settings_list: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in com.app.package:layout/exo_styled_settings_list: Error inflating class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerControlView.<init>(StyledPlayerControlView.java:550)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView.<init>(StyledPlayerView.java:418)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView.<init>(StyledPlayerView.java:234)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.inflateInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:1409)
        at com.app.package.databinding.ActivityAppTutorialBinding.inflate(ActivityAppTutorialBinding.java:99)
        at com.app.package.databinding.ActivityAppTutorialBinding.inflate(ActivityAppTutorialBinding.java:85)
        at com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity$mAppTutorialBinding$2.invoke(AppTutorialActivity.kt:59)
        at com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity$mAppTutorialBinding$2.invoke(AppTutorialActivity.kt:59)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity.getMAppTutorialBinding(AppTutorialActivity.kt:59)
        at com.app.package.login.AppTutorialActivity.onCreate(AppTutorialActivity.kt:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8006)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
2022-04-08 10:59:06.604 32468-32468/com.app.package E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3584)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Providing a LayoutTransition into RecyclerView is not supported. Please use setItemAnimator() instead for animating changes to the items in this RecyclerView
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutTransition(RecyclerView.java:2442)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.initFromAttributes(ViewGroup.java:785)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:711)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:704)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:689)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:685)
            ... 46 more
```

**exo_playback_control_view layout file:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#A6000000"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/exo_fullscreen_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exo_fullscreen_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_25"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_25"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_expand" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/exo_fullscreen_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_40"

            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_40"

            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/exo_position"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
                    android:id="@id/exo_progress"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/exo_duration"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exo_position"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/exo_duration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

One more thing to add. This code is in an activity. I mentioned it's an activity because I have added the same code in a fragment and it is working fine.

Comment: The stacktrace also mentions this: `Providing a LayoutTransition into RecyclerView is not supported`. See if you have a `RecyclerView` with `animateLayoutChanges` somewhere.

Comment: Can you post the `exo_playback_control_view` XML layout?

Comment: @LucaPizzini Updated, Please check. But even if I remove `app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_playback_control_view"` It still crashes

Comment: @DarShan The recyclerview mentioned in the crash log is from the exoplayer library only. I checked it as well.